# Proper instructions for a like button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm extremely frustrated with this right now, and everything I read is outdated (I've been googling for what feels like days).

All I'm trying to do is make a like button to a specific facebook page url (not a website url).

Obviously the number of likes on the facebook page should show up in the facebook like button (not like box).

I also want to use the 'share' button on the facebook like widget.

First of all, when I put the facebook page url in it says 0 likes, and that's the first problem (there are many likes).

Second, No matter what URL I try... it likes and immediately unlikes the page. Ive tried debugging and removing the facebook page url altogether, and trying just a standard URL instead.. it does the same thing.

I have installed tons of these in the past and now they are all being extremely buggy - WTF is facebook doing that I don't know about which could cause this to do this?

PS: I'm trying to also make this as simple as possible... I don't need all kinds of crazy features and app integration and garbage. I just want a like button to a page.

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: You generated these codes from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ?

Comment: Yep I did. Fresh too, this isn't old code I'm copying and pasting or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the codes for the like button from here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

Work around is, using a button to initiate a post request which automatically shares your user's feed via Graph API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/brent/feed?
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
```

This is yet another hack which sends users to sharer.php on the click of a button from where they can share.

Copied from another stackoverflow question :

```
<a id="fb-share" style='text-decoration:none;' type="icon_link" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=foo&amp;p[summary]=bar&amp;p[url]=https://www.foobar.com/&amp;p[images][0]=https://www.foobar.com/thumb.gif','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">
    <img src="img/share.gif" width="62" height="18" alt="Share"/>
</a>
```

Comment: It took 24 hours for it to "magically" work... so facebook problems (I also tried cache busting with linter and it didnt work). whatever though, it works now

Comment: What did you do for the share button you wanted? Just curious

Comment: I used the default code that facebook gives you, but it wouldnt work unless I had validated the page with the linter. once i had all the og tags, adn there were no errors, it took like 48 hours before it started working without erroring out (it would like and immediately unlike the page)